# Get pixel color from OpenLayers 2 WMS layer

Tags: openlayers

I need to get the pixel color from Image layer added on OSM.

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    x=e.x;
    y=e.y;  useCanvas(canvas,img,function(){
// get image data
var p = canvas.getContext('2d')
.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
 var coord = '<span>HEX: #'+rgbToHex(p[0],p[1],p[2])+'</span>'+
 '<span>  RGB:  rgb('+
  p[0]+','+
  p[1]+','+
  p[2]+')</span>';
 $('#status').html(coord);
```

Comment: Okay and what is the problem? What is your question?

Comment: the problem that i m getting the map from geoserver and i can't get the map to canvas context . Well , all i need is to put a specific img from geoserver to canvas to get the pixel color on specific position.

Comment: So, do you want to put a picture into a canvas, pixel by pixel?

Comment: Are you using OpenLayers.Layer.Image to create the layer? http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Image-js.html

Comment: no i m using  OpenLayers.Layer.WMS

Answer (score 0):

`layer.getTileData(point)` will give you the image and position on the image for any map coordinates.  `data.tile.getCanvasContext()` gives you the canvas context for the image.  It should work with any raster layer, either single image or tile grid.  Specifying `tileOptions: { crossOriginKeyword: 'anonymous' }` is essential if you want to access pixel data.

```js
//
    function rgbToHex(rgb){
        return (rgb && rgb.length === 4) ? "#" +
            ("0" + parseInt(rgb[1],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
            ("0" + parseInt(rgb[2],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
            ("0" + parseInt(rgb[3],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) : '';
    }

    var map, layer;
    function init(){
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', { projection: 'EPSG:4326' });
        layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
                'https://neo.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/wms/wms',
                { layers: 'BlueMarbleNG' },
                { tileOptions: { crossOriginKeyword: 'anonymous' } }
        );
        map.addLayer(layer);
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();

        map.events.register("mousemove", map, function(e){
            document.getElementById("docs").innerHTML = '';
            var point = map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy);
            var data = layer.getTileData(point);
            if (data) {
                var ctx = data.tile.getCanvasContext();
                if (ctx) {
                    var x = data.i;
                    var y = data.j;
                    // get image data
                    var p = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                    document.getElementById("docs").innerHTML = '<span>   HEX: '+ rgbToHex(p)+'</span>' +
                        '<span>   RGB: rgb(' + p[0] + ',' + p[1] + ',' + p[2] + ')</span>';
                }
            }
        });

    }
    init();
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0;}
#map { height: 80%; margin: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.12/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<pre id="docs"></pre>
```

Comment: Well this very helpful , but the thing is that  i m using openlayers 2.11 version.

Comment: I m getting "Uncaught TypeError: layer.getTileData is not a function" error

Comment: I've now tested with 2.12 where it works, but 2.11 does not support getTileData

Comment: so ? i really need a help

Comment: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data. at initialize.<anonymous>

Comment: Did you include `tileOptions: { crossOriginKeyword: 'anonymous' }` ?

Comment: yes ! 
 var ol_wms  = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
    "OSM",
    "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
    {layers: "basic"},
    {tileOptions: { crossOriginKeyword: 'anonymous' }}
);